# Which Designpattern should be used to share short-lived data between tabs of a TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, singleton

I am currently writing a mobile application that uses a TabBarController to show different views of the same data (map and list). Since my data is short-lived and needs to be updated every 2-10 minutes anyway I do not see any advantage in using CoreData and storing the data longterm.

Common sources on the internet suggest using CoreData (which i dont want to) or using the [Singleton design-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131094/should-i-avoid-a-singleton-as-datasource-for-a-tabbarcontroller-and-how-can-i). My first choice would also have been a Singleton, but apparently the Singleton is regarded as an [anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@johnsundell/avoiding-singletons-in-swift-5b8412153f9b) by a lot of iOS-developers.

What would be an appropriate method to handle this shared data between the two tabs of the TabBarController. As I am new to iOS development I am not entirely sure what the "iOS"-way of solving this problem would be. The data should always be the same in both tabs. A fetch should only be triggered once every few minutes or on reopening the app regardless of what tab the user is currently in.

Infos about my project:

- I am using Alamofire and PromiseKit on iOS and Javascript with
  Express for the backend (probably not relevant).
- The afore mentioned data is basically the
  only data within the app, apart from settings and a user profile.
- Subsequent ViewControllers (accessible from within the map and the list) would show and modify single entries of
  the data.

Comment: Have your data model post notifications.

Comment: Where would i store the data model though? And how would i trigger a data fetch? Wouldn't that be a Singleton solution?

Comment: Take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27619420/1630618).

Comment: Singleton always helps where you need a single source of truth. When it comes to data, it's good to have one such store. To start with you can use collection to store data in-memory. If you abstract out data layer, you can always replace it with CoreData later.

Comment: @vacawama Excellent thank you. That was an answer that i was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @RikeshSubedi Okay, did you look at the link in the comment above your comment? I guess something like that is what you mean, right?